# Amazon Reports API gives both child and parent ASINs. Is there any field by which i can identify both separately?

Tags: amazon-mws

I am using a couple of Reports via Amazon MWS API. Specifically the _GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_ and _GET_AFN_INVENTORY_DATA_. Both these reports gives the list of all products, both parent ASIN & child ASIN. I don't have the need for parent ASIN. And i don't see any field by which i can identify whether the item is a parent or a child. I have to manually open each ASIN's product page and then verify whether its a parent or child product.

Is there any field or any other API which will provide the list of items filtered with parent/child?

Answer (score 2):

Parent and child variation information can found in the "getMatchingProduct" call/response of the mws::products API.

> Contains product variation information, if applicable. If your search
>   criteria match a product that is identified by a variation parent
>   ASIN, the related VariationChild elements are contained in the
>   Relationships element. If your search criteria match a specific
>   variation child ASIN, the related VariationParent element is contained
>   in the Relationships element. Note: Because this operation does not
>   return all product attributes, it is possible to get VariationChild
>   elements with different ASIN values but the same variation element
>   values. These are distinct variation child ASINs even though product
>   attributes that differentiate them from each other are not returned.
>
> Variation attributes can be found in the VariationChild element of
>   default.xsd. Note: Variation attributes are not included in the
>   VariationChild element if the input ASIN values have more than 2000
>   combined VariationChild elements.

from: http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetMatchingProduct.html

Comment: Is there any way to retrieve them in bulk? instead of calling API with each ASIN?